# The constructor JSONArray(Object[]) is undefined

Tags: java, android, api

I just get this api class from the internet now i am integrating in my project everything is working fine but only getting one error is that constructor JSONArray is undefined .

```
private void fireEvent(mEvent event, Object obj) {
    try {
        //Called for EVERY event.         //getting error here 
        JSONArray arrayObj = obj instanceof JSONArray ? (JSONArray) obj : new JSONArray(new Object[] {obj});
        for (mEventListener listener : listeners) {
            listener.eventFired(this, event, arrayObj);
        }
        //Call the appropriate handler.
        switch (event) {
        case waiting:
            for (mEventListener listener : listeners) {
                listener.chatWaiting(this);
            }
            break;
        case connected:
            for (mEventListener listener : listeners) {
                listener.chatConnected(this);
            }
            break;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) You've forgotten to actually ask a question. It also seems like you probably want to look at the API documentation for JSONArray, since the error message in your title is quite clear.

Comment: I find this hard to understand as there is an object constructor `JSONArray(Object array)` So any single argument is valid. Show the exact error text.

Comment: Which api are you using? If I google JSONArray I get [http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html) as a result, which does have [a JSONArray constructor which allows `Object` as a single parameter](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html#JSONArray(java.lang.Object)). I agree with @weston that it's pretty odd that this errors occurs, if you are indeed using the JSONArray class I've linked.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen it's android, but that's a good point it's a fairly new constructor. So they need to compile against API19.

Answer (score 1):

That constructor is only available from API19: [`JSONArray(Object array)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html#JSONArray(java.lang.Object))

Therefore the most likely explanation is you are compiling against a lower API level.

You can use the collection constructor though, by passing a list:

```
JSONArray arrayObj = obj instanceof JSONArray
                      ? (JSONArray) obj
                      : new JSONArray(Arrays.asList(obj));
```

Comment: ok thank you But can i use JSONArray(); instead of that because eclipse forcing to do this

Comment: 1. I don't recommend using eclipse for android development. Use Android Studio. 2. No you can't use that. I've added code that should work.